# How to disarm traps in Dragon Age: Origins

Tags: dragon-age-origins

I was playing Dragon Age:Origins when I came across a trap; however, I was unable to interact with it (other than set it off).  As I was in combat at the time, I waited until I had killed all the dark-spawn in the area; however, I was still unable to get my rogue character to disable or even interact with the trap.

Am I missing something?

I don't have the "Trap Crafting" perk, but is that needed for Trap disarming as well as crafting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a rogue in your party in order to disarm a trap. So, that's the first thing to check. You will also need sufficient lockpicking skill, as discussed on [this](http://dragonage.neoseeker.com/wiki/Trap%20Detection%20and%20Disarm) and [other](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/950916-dragon-age-origins/52499784) pages. As with any rogue ability, Cunning always helps.

The basic formula seems to be
L = (cunning - 10) + 10 * [lockpicking rank]

Once a trap's been detected, you just have to right-click on the trap to interact with it (or highlight it with the D-pad and press the action button on consoles, as Kareen pointed out) and your rogue should disarm it. I'm not 100% certain if you need to be in active control of your rogue as I always was.

Also, remember that the faster you move, the less likely the trap is to be detected, so take your time in enemy dungeons.

If you satisfy all the conditions but interacting still does not work, double-check your key bindings just in case (PC only, obviously).

Comment: And if the OP is not playing on PC, I believe he'd need to target the trap using the D-Pad and pressing the action button.

Comment: Think it was cause my team wasn't close enough, so the game didn't think the battle was finished! couldn't quicksave till they were all together, which supports the idea. Howard how do you make your hero slow down? Is it a case of walk wait walk or can you make him walk instead of run?

Comment: @GarethJones On consoles, you can walk by not tilting the stick all the way up and just having it slightly upward. On PC, it would seem that the / key above the number pad, and would only work if you're using the W key.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same problem. If you are talking about disarming a tripwire you click on the endposts, NOT the wire.